# Circuit of a PWM DC motor speed controller for a 12V 10A DC motor

Tags: current, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, brushed-dc-motor

I saw many circuits for this, most of them were using 555 IC, I wanna use a 12V 15A switching power supply for this motor, so I need a high current PWM speed controller but I don't know how to design it or which component makes it powerfull and capable to be used for high current.

Another question is, the motor has huge initual current, so each time I turn the dial poetentiometer to speed up the motor, how much amps it will draw (more ir less than usuall)? and when I turn it down to stop the motor, will it make EMF/BackEMF until it stops?

Comment: I think you want to buy, not make, a speed controller. Either turn the control knob slowly, or look for a controller with soft start.